# Perché è "in Alba" con la preposizione "in"?

Tags: word-usage, regional, prepositions

Ecco l'inizio del romanzo *La luna e i falò*, di Cesare Pavese:

> C’è una ragione perché sono tornato in questo paese, qui e non invece a Canelli, a Barbaresco o **in Alba**.

Il fatto che con la cittadina di Alba si usi la preposizione "in", mentre invece si usa "a" con Canelli e Barbaresco (d'accordo alla regola che appare nelle grammatiche) ha attirato la mia attenzione, soprattutto perché ricordo che anche Fenoglio scrive sempre "in Alba". Per esempio, ecco una frase tratta dal racconto *I ventitré giorni della città di Alba*:

> Non che non n’avesse visti mai, al tempo che **in Alba** era di guarnigione il II Reggimento Cacciatori degli Appennini e che questi tornavano dall’aver rastrellato una porzione di Langa, ce n’era sempre da vedere uno o due con le mani legate col fildiferro e il muso macellato, ma erano solo uno o due, mentre ora c’erano tutti (come credere che ce ne fossero altri ancora?) e nella loro miglior forma.

Anche nell'introduzione al libro *Tutti i racconti* di Beppe Fenoglio, edito da Einaudi, Luca Bufano scrive:

> Piú che negli studi liceali, compiuti **in Alba** sotto la guida d’insegnanti d’eccezione, o in quelli universitari, iniziati a Torino nell’autunno del 1940 e interrotti due anni dopo dalla chiamata alle armi, anche Beppe Fenoglio, come molti suoi coetanei cresciuti all’ombra del fascismo, visse con la guerra partigiana l’esperienza piú alta e formativa.

Quindi non sembra si tratti della scelta stilistica di un autore. La mia domanda è: perché si usa la preposizione "in" prima di "Alba" invece di "ad", che è quello che ci si aspetterebbe d'accordo alla regola che appare nelle grammatiche?

---

**Aggiornamento:**

Ho recentemente scoperto che questo uso della preposizione "in" è attestato da Serianni nel suo libro *Italiano*. Nella sezione VIII.85 si può leggere:

> a) L'uso di *in* con i nomi di città era abbastanza diffuso anticamente: «mandare in Pisa» (*Novellino*), «va en Arezzo» (Guittone d'Arezzo), «se mai torni en Siena» (Cecco Angiolieri), «per mandarvi la figliuola in Granata», «in Messina tornati» (Boccaccio; esempi citati in ROHLFS 1966-69: 807). Ancora nell'Ottocento, il Manzoni preferisce «in Milano» a «a Milano»:  «andavano in giro facce, che in Milano non s'erano mai vedute» (*I Promessi Sposi*, XVI 55). 
>   b) Talvolta l'uso di *in* o di *a* con nomi di città oscilla anche per toponimi di una stessa area regionale; si veda questo esempio di Pavese: «C’è una ragione perché sono tornato in questo paese, qui e non invece *a* Canelli, *a* Barbaresco o *in* Alba.» (*La luna e i falò*, 9). 
>   c) In alcune zone l'uso di *in* con nomi di città è generalizzato, come si ricava da questo passo di Palazzeschi in cui lo scrittore descrive il disagio, anche linguistico, delle fiorentine sorelle Materassi costrette a partire per le Marche: «per andare *in* Ancona si doveva cambiare a Faenza. Che cos'era mai questa Ancona per cui si doveva cambiare, se per andare a Roma non si doveva cambiare proprio nulla? E dava loro noia quell''in' che si rendeva necessario per pronunziarne il nome. Per tutte le altre città si dice: '*a Roma, a Napoli, a  Milano, a Torino, a Firenze*'» (*Sorelle Materassi*, 85). 
>   d) Nello stato in luogo degli odonimi al tipo «*in* via Cavour», di uso più generale e tradizionale, si affianca il tipo romanesco e meridionale «*a* via Cavour», in parte debordato dall'uso locale a quello letterario (Moravia, ecc.) e giornalistico; cfr. BALDELLI 1964: 335. 
>   e) Nello stile formale e ufficiale può aversi *in* con una qualifica professionale seguita da un toponimo: «Ringrazio il sig. Pietro Bilancioni *avvocato in Ravenna*» (Carducci, *Opere*).

Da notare come Serianni menziona anche l'uso della preposizione "in" nel linguaggio burocratico spiegato da @user070221 nella sua risposta, ma lo fa come un caso diverso (la lettera e) nell'elenco sopra citato). Dunque, anche Serianni esclude che gli esempi con "in Alba" o "in Ancona" citati nel suo libro corrispondano a questo uso della preposizione "in" nello "stile formale e ufficiale". Sembra piuttosto trattarsi di un uso regionale.

Comment: Lo stesso vale per “in Adria” (da dove viene mia madre), anche se l'uso si va perdendo.

Comment: Cfr. anche con [*Ascanio in Alba*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascanio_in_Alba) per un esempio completamente scollegato da Fenoglio (anche se non si tratta della stessa città)

Comment: Penso che la tua domanda debba essere più precisa. Un conto è chiedere se sia “grammaticalmente” corretto usare la preposizione *in* invece che *a* riferendosi ad una città. Ma altra cosa   è chiedere perché uno scrittore abbia usato la preposizione *in* invece che *a* in un suo libro.  Nel primo caso fonti affidabili descrivono i contesti dove *in* viene spesso usato. Nel secondo caso si può dare solo un’opinione personale  che, se non sbaglio, sono off-topic su questo sito.

Comment: @user070221: Non è soltanto un autore. Nella domanda ci sono testi di tre autori diversi: Pavese, Fenoglio e Luca Bufano. E, a quanto pare da Google Ngram, ci sono altri autori che scrivono o scrivevano "in Alba".

Comment: Quindi? Uno o più autori, comunque la domanda rimane basata su opinioni personali.

Comment: Dovremmo forse trovare una casistica più ampia. Al momento, visto che sia Alba che Adria cominciano con la A, penserei a una scelta di suono, per evitare due A di seguito (l’eventuale D eufonica non risolverebbe “il problema”). L’eufonica non è grammaticale, e in ogni caso l’uso è sempre più forte delle regole, soprattutto con le preposizioni.

Comment: @Benedetta: E anche "in Ancona" (vedi quello che dice Serianni) e "in Ariano" (vedi la risposta di egreg). La citazione delle *Sorelle Matterassi* («E dava loro noia quell''in' che si rendeva necessario per pronunziarne il nome.») mi fa anche pensare a delle ragioni d'eufonia, ma poi quello che dice Serianni («In alcune zone l'uso di in con nomi di città è generalizzato, come si ricava da questo passo di Palazzeschi») mi confonde.

Comment: @Charo: Ho fatto un esame con Serianni; spero non si dispiacerà se dico che la frase per spiegare quell’uso c) non è proprio chiara. In pratica vuol dire che in Toscana si usa sempre la preposizione A, però nella citazione non ci sono città con la A, se non Ancona.

Answer (score 5):

Escluderei il linguaggio burocratico. Si tratta solo di eufonia.

Invece della “d eufonica” che non appartiene propriamente ai dialetti settentrionali, viene adoperato *in*. Mia nonna, mia madre e le sue sorelle hanno sempre detto *in Adria*, la loro città, sia con verbi di moto sia con verbi di stato; analogamente per *in Ariano*. Nessun dubbio, però, su *a Este*.

Lo stesso vale, evidentemente, per Pavese e Fenoglio riguardo alla città di Alba, come confermato dalla preposizione davanti agli altri toponimi che non cominciano per *a*.

Il titolo *Ascanio in Alba*, suggerito da Denis Nardin, è un altro esempio.

[Un Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20Alba%2Cad%20Alba&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20Alba%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cad%20Alba%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20Alba%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cad%20Alba%3B%2Cc0) mostra che “in Alba” era la forma prevalente fino intorno al 1920, rispetto a “ad Alba”. Si nota un’impennata della seconda forma negli anni 1920–1930, probabilmente dovuta a imposizioni grammaticali a scuola nei primi anni del ’900.

Comment: Suona verosimile. (Con Ngram ci si può anche far mostrare il rapporto – o altre operazioni – fra i numeri di occorrenze di due forme, come [qui](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+Alba%2Fad+Alba&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28in%20Alba%20/%20ad%20Alba%29%3B%2Cc0), che mette per esempio in evidenza che dalla fine degli anni '30 “ad Alba” sembra essersi stabilizzata sul doppio delle occorrenze di “in Alba”.)

Answer (score 2):

Secondo questo estratto dal sito di [Zanichelli](https://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/lingua-e-scuola/posta-del-professore/e-corretto-dire-abito-a-milano-o-abito-in-milano/) la preposizione ***in*** riferita a città è un uso principalmente burocratico:

> Si dice “abito a Milano” o “abito in Milano”?
>   Ultimamente ho trovato spesso l’espressione ‘abito in Milano’: ho sempre pensato che fosse corretto dire e scrivere ‘abito a Milano”

——-

> secondo noi l’uso prevalente segue le regole deducibili dai seguenti esempi:
>
> – abito a Parigi, a Lecco, a Cervinia [città, paese];
>
> – abito in Brianza, in provincia di Parma, in Piemonte, nel Lazio, in Ungheria, in Australia [zona, regione, stato, continente];
>
> – abito a Capri, all’Elba, alle Hawai, a Bali [isola piccola o medio piccola];
>
> – abito in Corsica, in Sicilia, nel Borneo [isola medio grande o grande].
>
> - ***Invece ‘abitante in Milano’ è tipico del linguaggio burocratico.***

Da [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/in-preposizione_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/):

> a Milano, a Roma, a Venezia, a Trieste
>
> ***Nel ➔registro formale e ufficiale, tuttavia si può usare anche in con i nomi di città***, soprattutto dopo un nome che indica una professione
>
> Carlo De Stefano ingegnere in Torino

Comment: Giustissimo, ma Pavese e Fenoglio non erano burocrati, e quindi la domanda rimane aperta...

Comment: E soprattutto, Pavese scrive "a Canelli", "a Barbaresco", ma invece "in Alba". Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, comunque!

Comment: @DaG - quello che lo ”Zanichelli“ intende dire è che l’espressione è probabilmente mutuata dal linguaggio burocratico. Linguaggio a cui siamo tutti esposti, e Pavese non fa eccezione,

Comment: @user070221: La tua è un'interessante ipotesi, ma non spiega, come è stato fatto notare, perché per altre città usino la preposizione “a”.

Comment: @Charo: E nel passo di Bufano che citi, nel giro di due righe, compare “in Alba” e “a Torino”. Sospetto che sia in gioco, più o meno consciamente, qualche motivazione eufonica, come se suonassero male le ripetute “a” in “ad Alba”.

Comment: @DaG - licenza poetica? Bizzarria di uno scrittore? Chissà?

Comment: @user070221: Siamo d'accordo sul “chissà?”, e infatti è proprio il motivo per cui l'OP ha posto la domanda: chi lo sa?

Comment: Come ho scritto nell'aggiornamento che ho fatto al testo della domanda, penso che anche Serianni escluda che questo sia l'uso della preposizione "in" che fanno Pavese, Fenoglio e Bufano nelle citazioni che ho messo (questo uso burocratico corrisponde alla lettera e) nell'elenco di Serianni).