# Variazione regionale nell'uso delle preposizioni di luogo

Tags: regional, prepositions

Nei [commenti](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11005/andare-a-vs-andare-in-places#comment25867_11007) ad una recente domanda DaG faceva notare che in centro Italia l'uso della preposizione *in* davanti ai nomi delle vie è percepito come inusuale, e finanche scorretto, ed è preferita la preposizione *a* (che, viceversa, il mio orecchio settentrionale percepisce come scorretta).

Questo mi ha ricordato l'uso toscano di *andare a giro*, rispetto all'italiano standard *andare in giro* e mi ha fatto pensare che magari ci sia qualcosa di più generale da dire.

> **Q:** È possibile individuare qualche tendenza generale nell'uso delle varie preoposizioni di luogo nelle varie regioni d'Italia?

Comment: Ad esempio in Liguria si dice _andare a spiaggia_ invece di andare alla spiaggia.

Comment: @abarisone [Invece di "andare **in** spiaggia"](http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_407.html), vuoi dire :P

Comment: Un'aggiunta del tutto collaterale e “a orecchio” a quello che dicevo lì. In italiano standard, sia “a” che “in”, in opportune collocazioni, possono introdurre sia stati in luogo che moti a luogo. Trovo che alcune differenze tra diverse varietà regionali siano appunto in queste collocazioni, con una generalizzazione (ma non esclusiva) verso “a” al Centro e verso “in” a Nord. A complicare ulteriormente le cose ci si mette anche l'uso degli articoli o meno (mangio a mensa, alla mensa, in mensa...).

Comment: Se ne parla in parte nell'«aggiornamento» a [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10446/707).