# Uso regionale della preposizione "in" con nomi di città (intorno ad Ancona)

Tags: word-usage, regional, prepositions

Come si può leggere in [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10446/707), la sezione VIII.85 dell'*Italiano* di Serianni riporta questa informazione:

> c) In alcune zone l'uso di *in* con nomi di città è generalizzato, come si ricava da questo passo di Palazzeschi in cui lo scrittore descrive il disagio, anche linguistico, delle fiorentine sorelle Materassi costrette a partire per le Marche: «per andare *in* Ancona si doveva cambiare a Faenza. Che cos'era mai questa Ancona per cui si doveva cambiare, se per andare a Roma non si doveva cambiare proprio nulla? E dava loro noia quell''in' che si rendeva necessario per pronunziarne il nome. Per tutte le altre città si dice: '*a Roma, a Napoli, a  Milano, a Torino, a Firenze*'» (*Sorelle Materassi*, 85).

Non sono sicura di aver colto il senso di questa spiegazione. Devo capire che in certe  zone d'Italia, in particolare in una regione intorno ad Ancona, si usa la preposizione "in" con tutti i nomi di città e comuni? Cioè, per esempio, si dice "in Roma", "in Torino", "in Castelfidardo", ecc.? Oppure questa preposizione si usa soltanto con i nomi che cominciano con la lettera "a" come accade appunto nella espressione "in Ancona"?

Comment: In effetti la citazione da cui a suo dire "si ricava che l'uso di in è generalizzato" dimostrebbe il contrario: "per tutte le altre città si dice a". Semplicemente Ancona comincia per a (come da discussione nell'altra domanda).

Comment: Una piccola correzione: Sorelle Materassi (con una sola “t”).

Comment: Come dicevo anche nella discussione sotto il precedente post, l’esempio fatto da Serianni non è adatto, o quantomeno non è ben introdotto. Ho il dubbio che l’uso generalizzato di IN + nome di città sia geografico. Mi è capitato, ad esempio, di vederlo nel linguaggio della curia (cattolica) di Roma (mentre noi romani usiamo sempre la A). Non ho però trovato link di riferimento.

Comment: Grazie, @Benedetta!

Comment: @OldManofAran, Benedetta: Un attimo: non so niente dell'italiano regionale delle Marche, ma nell'universo del romanzo di Palazzeschi le protagoniste hanno sentito anconetani dire "in Ancona", mentre a loro risulta che per tutte le altre città si dica "a X", e quindi confondono – non sono linguiste – una peculiarità dell'italiano regionale con una peculiarità della città in cui sono costrette ad andare.

Comment: @DaG ma nella frase stessa che citano "per andare IN Ancona si deve cambiare A Faenza"

Comment: @OldManofAran: E quindi? Faenza non è nelle Marche. Citandomi: «nell'universo del romanzo di Palazzeschi le protagoniste hanno sentito anconetani dire "in Ancona", mentre a loro risulta che _per tutte le altre città si dica "a X"_».

Comment: @DaG Quindi può essere (non ho letto il romanzo, quindi immagino tu abbia ragione), ma di sicuro non si deduce da quella citazione.

Comment: @DaG: per me il problema è che la citazione si usi per dimostrare che «In alcune zone l'uso di IN con nomi di città è generalizzato», visto che Ancona inizia con la A, caso che rientrerebbe in quelli di cui abbiamo parlato nell’altro thread, a maggior ragione perché più avanti si legge: «quell''in' che si rendeva necessario per pronunziarne il nome». (Potrebbe essere un mio problema di comprensione del testo).

Comment: @Benedetta: Personalmente non mi ha mai molto convinto l'argomentazione “eufonica”, tra l'altro perché a questo scopo esiste “ad” come forma alternativa di “a” (non che debba convincere me; dico solo che non è del tutto pacifica), e viceversa in certi registri e ambiti regionali “in” si usa indipendentemente dalla lettera che segue. È questo che sta dicendo Serianni (anche se l'esempio scelto non è convincente), nonché le altre fonti citate appunto in quel thread.

Comment: Ciao io sono originaria della provincia di Ascoli Piceno. Capita di andare IN Ascoli. Nonostante sto molto attenta al linguaggio e sono curiosa, non direi mai vado ad Ancona , e meno che meno vado ad Ascoli. Non si dice proprio qua da noi. Ovvio diciamo vado a Fermo, vado a Macerata.

Answer (score 2):

Leggendo i commenti al canto XVIII del *Purgatorio* di Dante Alighieri scritti da Anna Maria Chiavacci Leonardi, nata nelle Marche, nel volume pubblicato da Mondadori, ho trovato questo:

> Forse Dante raccolse **in Verona** una tradizione su questo abate accidioso di più di un secolo prima, ma la cosa non è probabile, né necessaria. Nulla ne sanno i suoi commentatori, e lo stesso Pietro, che visse e scrisse **in Verona**, osserva soltanto: «Vitium accidiae multum inter claustrales frequentatur».

Allora mi sono messa a ricercare meglio in questo libro e ho trovato altri esempi di uso della preposizione "in" con nomi di città e cittadine:

> Nel marzo viene **in Firenze** il principe Carlo Martello, figlio di Carlo II d’Angiò re di Napoli, per incontrare il padre che torna dalla Francia; Dante lo conosce, forse come giovane cavaliere del corteggio che il Comune mette a disposizione del principe, e stringe con lui un rapporto di stima e amicizia.

> [...] l’Impero romano è considerato vacante dalla morte di Federico II in *Conv*. IV, III 6, in quanto i tre imperatori eletti in seguito in Germania – Rodolfo d’Asburgo, Adolfo di Nassau e Alberto d’Austria, regnante nel 1300 e a cui qui ci si rivolge  – non furono mai incoronati **in Roma** [...].

> [...] fu valente giureconsulto e, secondo Benvenuto, fu anche dottore di leggi **in Bologna**. Mentre era magistrato **in Siena**, condannò [...].

> Il costrutto ipotetico (*s’io fosse*...) sembra riecheggiare i vv. 9-10 dell’epigrafe posta sulla tomba di Iacopo nella chiesa di San Domenico **in Fano** [...].

Anche nelle note e nei commenti di Anna Maria Chiavacci Leonardi al *Paradiso* di Dante (Mondadori) se ne possono trovare molti esempi. Eccone alcuni:

> [...] santo martire venerato in tutta la cristianità, al cui nome si intitola una delle maggiori basiliche romane; di origine spagnola, diacono **in Roma**, fu arso vivo su una graticola durante la persecuzione di Valeriano nel 258.

> A pronunciare i tre discorsi sono scelti tre personaggi legati personalmente, e affettivamente, al potere politico condannato: il principe angioino nel primo caso, Cunizza da Romano nel secondo (della casa cioè che aveva dominato **in Padova** nella prima metà del secolo) e un vescovo, cioè un rappresentante della Chiesa, nel terzo.

> [...]   presso il vescovo di Feltre, Alessandro Novello di Treviso, si erano rifugiati nel 1312 quattro fuorusciti ferraresi, che fuggivano da Pino della Tosa, vicario di Roberto d’Angiò e della Chiesa **in Ferrara**. Il vescovo, cedendo alla pressioni di Pino e dei trevisani, li consegnò al vicario angioino, che li fece decapitare.

> Ma la testimonianza di Pietro di Dante, che fra l’altro visse **in Verona** dopo la morte del padre, sembra su questo punto decisiva: [...].

Quindi, in vista di questi esempi, è chiaro che  Serianni sta spiegando che esistono zone in Italia (in particolare nelle Marche) in cui si usa la preposizione "in" con tutti i nomi di città, non soltanto con quelli che cominciano con la lettera "a".

Comment: se ne trova un esempio molto chiaro qui https://www.bikeitalia.it/2019/04/16/cuore-salite-piede-a-terra-le-marche-di-michele-scarponi/: 'Un’altra tappa di avvicinamento alla giornata della pedalata di domenica l’abbiamo percorsa tutti insieme giovedì 11 aprile “in Ancona” (gli anconetani dicono così, ndr) dove [...]'

Comment: Grazie, @GrandTorini! Mi era chiaro che si dice "in Ancona", ma non ero sicura che gli anconetani dicessero anche, per esempio, "in Padova".

Comment: ho il dubbio che si tratti di una cosa del parlato e/o di una forma un po' antiquata. Per es. "anconatoday" riporta 'Marche, il bollettino di oggi venerdì 18 dicembre: 68 nuovi casi ad Ancona' 
 (https://www.anconatoday.it/attualita/bollettino-coronavirus-oggi-18-dicembre-2020-marche.html). Cercando online non riesco a capire quanto questa forma sia tuttora diffusa o se sia applicata ad altre città ... bisognerebbe chiedere ad un anconetano