# "Cappella Paolina del Quirinale in Roma": perché si usa "in" e non "a"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Oggi ho messo la radio (RAI Radio 3 classica). Ritrasmettevano una "registrazione effettuata  presso la cappella Paolina del Quirinale in Roma": hanno detto proprio così.

L'uso della preposizione "in" ha attirato la mia attenzione: mi sono chiesta: perché usano "in" e non "a"? Poi ho ricercato "Quirinale in Roma" su Google e mi sono apparse parecchie occorrenze.  Si trova su siti web di natura molto diversa: annunci di eBay, informazioni turistiche, pubblicità di restoranti, informazioni culturali, Wikipedia, ecc.

[Questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/10446) riporta quello che spiega l'*Italiano* di Serianni riguardo diversi usi delle preposizioni "in" e "a".
Tuttavia, per me non è niente chiaro che l'utilizzo che se ne fa in questa espressione corrisponda a nessuno di quegli usi. In una risposta a quella domanda si è anche menzionato che nel linguaggio burocratico si può usare "in" invece di "a" con i nomi di città. Tuttavia, non mi sembra che il linguaggio usato in tutti quelli siti web e nel programma di radio appartenga al registro burocratico.

Sapreste spiegarmi per quale ragione si usa la preposizione "in" in questa locuzione?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111294/discussion-on-question-by-charo-cappella-paolina-del-quirinale-in-roma-perche).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La questione è abbastanza semplice. Nessuno direbbe *in Roma* chiacchierando con amici. Al contrario, potrebbe dire *in Alba* perché dalle parti di Alba così è l'uso per Alba, non per altre città, così com'era per Adria.<sup>1</sup>

Perché non *ad Alba* o *ad Adria*? Semplice: la “d” eufonica è toscana. In altre zone d'Italia sembra frequente l'uso di *in* invece di *a*, ma queste non rappresentano usi tali da parlare di alternanza, solo di uso locale.

La preposizione di stato in luogo in questi casi è *a*, per la vasta maggioranza dei parlanti.

Bene, perché mai l'annunciatrice radiofonica dice *la cappella Paolina del Quirinale in Roma*? Linguaggio aulico, latineggiante.

In latino la preposizione è indiscutibilmente *in*, mentre *ad* indica moto a luogo. Si può usare in italiano? Certo, e ci sono molti esempi. Targhe accanto alle porte che dicono “Pinco Pallino, notaio in Vattelapesca” (o magari *notaro* se il signor, pardon, dottor Pallino è molto aulico e pomposo) sono la norma.

Perché Serianni non lo dice? O, perbacco! Lo dice eccome!

> a) L'uso di *in* con i nomi di città era abbastanza diffuso anticamente: «mandare in Pisa» (*Novellino*), «va en Arezzo» (Guittone d'Arezzo), «se mai torni en Siena» (Cecco Angiolieri), «per mandarvi la figliuola in Granata», «in Messina tornati» (Boccaccio; esempi citati in ROHLFS 1966-69: 807). Ancora nell'Ottocento, il Manzoni preferisce «in Milano» a «a Milano»: «andavano in giro facce, che in Milano non s'erano mai vedute» (*I Promessi Sposi*, XVI 55).

La chiave è “anticamente”: “diffuso anticamente” non significa che oggi sia “proibito”. Invece, significa che chi lo adopera vuole dare una patina di “linguaggio nobile” al suo parlato (o scritto, come nel caso del pomposo dottor Pallino).

---

<sup>1</sup> Almeno lo era al tempo di Fenoglio, per Alba, o dei miei genitori, per Adria. L'influsso dell'italiano sulla lingua locale può aver modificato l'uso.

Comment: Solo una nota: "dire *in Alba* perché dalle parti di Alba così è l'uso" non è vero: "in Alba" è molto meno usato che "ad Alba". E' vero che in Piemontese si dice comunemente "n'Alba, n'Asti, n'Aic" (in Alba, in Asti, in Acqui), ma in Italiano no.

Comment: @egreg: Divertente: l'ho trovato persino per [un'altra Alba](https://www.idealista.com/it/alquiler-viviendas/alba-de-tormes-salamanca/) (immagino qui sia un errore).

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Grazie, ho aggiunto una nota.